# Issues with using application settings

Tags: c#, winforms

very new to C#. I'm trying to create a restaurant POS as one of my beginner projects. Currently, I'm working on the "total sales", where I basically add up all of the total prices of orders that have been processed. I'm not sure what to put as my value for the current total.

In Program.cs, I created this:
`public static decimal total = 0;`

And in the form that actually affects this, I put this in:

```
        private void updateTotal()
        {
            Program.total = Program.total + sumTot;
            Properties.Settings.Default.totalRev = Program.total;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

        }
```

In this, the totalRev is the value I saved in the application settings. Clearly, however, as I have made Program.total equal to 0 in the Program.cs, rather than adding the new order price (sumTot) to the existing total sales, I'm adding them to 0 so I replace the total sales with the new order price. I'm sure this is a silly mistake but I can't wrap my head around what I can replace the public static decimal with, or if this is some other issue.

Comment: You need to specify that the setting is a *user-scoped* setting. Only those can be changed. You should change the `Scope` value of the setting to `User`

Comment: If this is about scope, yes it is in a current user scope.

Comment: Just for learning

Answer (score 0):

Soo.... if I am understanding your issue correctly, you are simply missing the initilazation of `Program.total` with the "old" value stored in the user.config

Therefor in the [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) add those lines

```
class Program
{
    static Program()
    {
        Program.total = Properties.Settings.Default.totalRev;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, so sorry, I don't exactly know what you mean by static constructor, but if this means to put this inside Program.cs, it came up with error lines under the entire statement.

Comment: did you copy&paste the class definition aswell? `class Program...` or only the static constructor `static Program()...` ?

Comment: @user741 - note: my code was missing a `;` at the end

Comment: Yes, in Program.cs, I copied and pasted the entire statement, and the red line persisted under the entire statement.

Comment: @user741 - here a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeDk9.png

Comment: @user741 - glad I could be of help